# “I work in” vs. “I work at”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

We use the preposition *at* with specific places. For example,

> I work at Intel.

In the following sentence I think that we should use *in* instead:

> I work in a kindergarten.

Is it also correct to say

> I work at a kindergarten.

Assuming that *at* is also correct, then is *in* better than *at* here,
or are they both equally acceptable, or is *at* better?

Comment: I don't have any references, but I think we use *in* with generic terms and *at* with named ones. I work *in* a hospital but I work *at* St. Thomas.

Answer (score 4):

*X at Y* means X is a place, and Y is close enough to X that if we wanted to find Y, we'd first have to find X.  A place is large amount of space where things can be built or where things can happen.

*X in Y* means X surrounds Y, either physically or logically.

Buildings surround you, so when you enter a building, you are said to be *in* it, and can say you work *in* a building.

Businesses sometimes aren't just a building or room in a building, they have a campus, etc.  Or maybe they have multiple buildings.  So then they can be elevated to "place status" and therefore you use *at*.

> I work in a kindergarten.

You're saying there's a room or building labeled "kindergarten" and that's where you work.  If it's part of a school or greater institution, this is proper to say.

> I work at a kindergarten.

You're saying there's a *place* called a kindergarten and you work there.  This gives the impression it's a separate building, with it's own parking lot, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Both of those are poor examples for use of the chosen prepositions.

You would not say "I work in a kindergarten".

Nor would you say "I work at a kindergarten".

The best choice for the prepositions given would be:

"I work in a kindergarten classroom".

It would be odd to say "I work at a kindergarten classroom".

It would be normal to say "I work at a school."  But not "...at a kindergarten".