# Is there any difference between using "in" and "at" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, difference

> I work in/at an investment firm.

Is there any difference between using in and at in this sentence?

Comment: In certain contexts *some* native speakers might claim there's a nuance of difference between ***in / at / for*** here, but for all practical purposes they're equivalent. One that *is* usually different is ***with***, which tends to imply ***...as an [equal / independent] partner*** rather than ***...as an employee***.

Comment: *for* might imply freelancing

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90379/work-for-work-in-work-at

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“I work in” vs. “I work at”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106201/i-work-in-vs-i-work-at)

Answer (score 0):

A regular employee would most likely say, "I work at an investment firm."
If using the company name, it would be more common to say, "I work for Shearson/Lehman."
Other variations:
"I work with Dan at McDonald's."
"I with with an investment group."
"I'm a partner at Radle, Harrison and Liberfarb."
"I am employed by Tingstofel and Flanders."

The differences are very subtle.